# Local Transport Fare design: how to relate departures, destinations and locations

Tags: database-design, erd

I am doing a conceptual model for local transportation fare app

The goal is for users to quickly check the current fare and the previous fare from one location to the other. Sometimes, the government will increase the fare (which will be the current fare) and after a while or so, they will return to the previous fare.  Please see the final view of the app below.

[image: User view]

Since there is a many to many relationship between Departure and Destination, I will need a bridge entity to solved that, but how do I relate that to location since I do not want to have repetition on locations?

Please see my ERD below

[image: ERD]

Thank you for you time, really appreciated

Comment: Please put your schema and table content example as text in your question, avoid images.

Comment: What's the point of the tables `departure` and `destination`? I mean why doesn't point `fare.dpt_id` (or `fare.det_id`) directly to `location`?

Comment: seems to be one to many, but yeah... why not one not one table for places?  also is location name really a good natural key?  for instance, stadiums often change their name.